# Android Dual Boot bootmgr is missing

Tags: windows, boot, android

Im trying to dual boot android 5.2 on my HP Slate 500 tablet, i used unetbootin to install the ISO on my pen drive and then restarted and went to the boot menu and selected my usb stick and this message appeared >BOOTMGR is missing press ctrl...<

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What format is the USB drive? NTFS? FAT32?

Comment: The format is NTFS

Comment: Try reformatting it as FAT32 then reimaging the drive with the ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unetbootin requires the USB drive to be formatted as FAT32 for it to successfully image an ISO.

Reformat the drive as FAT32 and try again.